# How to keep currency format text outside the textbox of a Price Column while updating the Price in ASPX Web Forms?

Tags: c#, aspxgridview

In my UpdateProducts.aspx, this is what I have done:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox1" runat="server" DataField="Product_Price" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:0.00} AUD",Eval("Product_Price"))%>'/>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers with decimals only" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
          <asp:Button ID ="Button7" runat="server" OnClick="Price_Update_Click" CommandArgument="Button7" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I run the aspx page by using the code above everything is working perfectly. The only minor issue is even "AUD" is included in the text box value for Product_Price column. In other words, the Price_Column value displays as "65.55 AUD" inside the text box which I don't want.
But what I want is AUD to be displayed besides the text box (but not inside the text box).
In other words, the text box value for the Product_Price column should display  as "65.55" AUD

In order to achieve it, this is what I have tried in UpdateProducts.cs

```
protected void Price_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
            int index = gvr.RowIndex;
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox1");
            decimal Price;
            bool prc = decimal.TryParse(box1.Text, out Price);
            var PriceString = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text.Replace(" AUD", "");

            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            string ProductNo = row.Cells[0].Text;

if (Price > 00.00m)
            {
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateProductPrice", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", Price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNo", ProductNo);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox("Price has been updated");
                DisplayProducts();
            }

            else if (Price == 00.00m || prc == false)
            {
                Label5.Text = "Please don't keep the price blank";
                DisplayProducts();
            }

        }
```

Even after using  [  decimal Price;
            bool prc = decimal.TryParse(box1.Text, out Price);
            var PriceString = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text.Replace(" AUD", "");   ] ... I am not able to update the product price.

It would be helpful if the recommended syntax solution is provided.

Comment: Note that the datatype in SQL Server for Product_Price Column is MONEY.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to solve it.
All I had to do was to add a Label.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox1" runat="server" DataField="Product_Price" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:0.00}",Eval("Product_Price"))%>'/>
          <asp:Label ID="Label6" Text="AUD" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers with decimals only" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
          <asp:Button ID ="Button7" runat="server" OnClick="Price_Update_Click" CommandArgument="Button7" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```